# How to create multiple caller functions by another function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function call stack like this, but so that it goes to `caller_1_100`:

```cpp
void callee(void) {
    // prints out final call stack
}
void caller_1_3(void) { callee(); }
void caller_1_2(void) { caller_1_3(); }
void caller_1_1(void) { caller_1_2(); }
```

I know I could use a recursive function to do this, but for now I want to try out both ways.

So I was wondering if there was a way to create this sort of caller functions automatically in C++, as I want to make the function call stack to go down at least 100 in depth.

However, from what I searched it doesn't seem possible in C++? Should I use python or some other language to create then change to C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function template with a specialization for your base case.  For example:

```
template <size_t I>
void caller_1()
{
    caller_1<I + 1>();
}

template <>
void caller_1<100>()
{
    callee();
}
```

Keep in mind that since templates are resolved at compile time any decent optimizing compiler will almost certainly optimize out the intermediate calls, so you probably won't see them in a stack trace.  See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1468f054f02ec1d).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm hoping that maybe if I use -O0 and __attribute__((noinline)) it won't happen.

Comment: Awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you want to have at least 100 in depth, it can be 100, 200, or others. This is like having dynamic function definition. It is not a feature of a compiled language. JS or Python can achieve this more easily.

A solution with C++ can be having a class with a `id` property and a public function which will be called by others. Then instantiate `X` instances of the class where `X` is your depth and call the function of the instances as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that what I was trying to do was creating a dynamic function. This sounds like a great idea.